# FBX Importer AssertionError (unknown location -1) when importing .fbx from wow model viewer

Tags: import

Using version 2.75 I am unable to import .fbx files from WoW model viewer into blender.

Attempting to do so throws an AssertionError.

```
Assertion Error

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Does anyone know what is going on here and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

That kind of issue must be reported to [our tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug), with an .fbx example file to reproduce it…

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

I had a similar problem but I could not find a solution. It turned out that `Visual Studio 2013` (Professional; I don't know whether the Express version is enough) and `Unity` (a gaming engine; in case you didn't know) were both able to import the file correctly.

Finally, I imported the file into `Visual Studio 2013` and saved it as a `.obj` file which could then be imported correctly into blender.

**EDIT**

However, it worked correctly using the [Blender 2.72b](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.72/) version.